# ASP.Net 1.1 to ASP.Net 4.0 Migration

Tags: asp.net

We are migrating our existing code written in ASP.Net 1.1 to ASP.Net 4.0. We also need to migrate our web controls as well.

We have 50% or more pages has DataGrid used and from ASP.Net 2.0 we have GridView the only difference i found that in

1. ASP.Net 1.1 DataGrid has "Item" based property, event and method while in GridView it is "RowItem" based
2. ASP.Net 4.0 and 4.5 - Both support DataGrid as well

if we do not change to GridView as if we do that  we need to also change code and  event and reTest the changes.  as we have more than 400 pages and for each page change it took around 1 Hour to change & Test

My question is what will be drawback

If we continue with DataGrid is there any drawback on performance or any other consideration to change this is better way go to ahead.

Thanks